# Laptop CPU runs unnecessarily fast when charging

Tags: cpu, battery, charger

When I connect the charger to my laptop it immediately jumps to around 4GHz on all 4 cores, sometimes even 4,7 GHz. It also draws around 40 watts, settling to around 25 after a while, instead of below 10 when powered by battery. As you can guess, this makes my fans spin up massively as the CPU gets quite hot. How can I prevent this from happening.

Laptop is an Asus Zenbook 15, with an i7 10510U and a GTX 1650 Max-Q

Comment: Use Task Manager or System Monitor to determine *what process* is using the CPU excessively.

Comment: If you left-click the battery icon in your taskbar can you set it to recommended? It sounds like it is set to high-performance. That might help... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-power-slider

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It seems I have found the source of my issue, it is related to my USB-Ethernet adapter. The system process was using the CPU, and further analysis using Windows performance recorder and analyser suggests it is an issue with said adapter. However, I still don't know how to fix this.